# Import Excel File to DataGridView then Update DataGridView to DataBase (Using C# and Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, database-connection

[See Image Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unp7D.png)

I can currently update it to the grid view successfully.

But I dont know how to save it to the database yet.

This is the code I used for excel to datagridview

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
```

the name of my dataset: caDataSet

the name of my bindingsource: clBindingSource

the name of my tableadapter: clTableAdapter

the name of my database: ca.mdf

the name of my table in database: cl

variables in table include: custno, bcust,name,addr,ket,......,client

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: did u change anything in `datagridview` and save those changes to database manes excel sheet again?

Comment: noo error.
it take data from excel, it works. but it doesn't go to the database but only datagrid view. when i try adding data into database, datagridview work properly.